# Can I only travel on the second leg of a one-stop flight?

Tags: hidden-city-ticketing

Let's say there is an available booking from A-B-C, but I actually live in B. Can I book the flights and travel on the B-C flight only? I'm asking this because the A-B-C ticket is considerably cheaper than B-C ticket.

If that is not possible, are there any tricks to take advantage of the cheaper A-B-C price compared to B-C?

Comment: This is called "hidden city ticketing". Airlines don't like that. You can try the opposite: find a B-C-D flight that is cheaper than B-C. But you'll have issues with the return flight which will be cancelled when you don't board C-D, and one-way fares are usually much more expensive. And all the usual caveats apply: the airline can re-route you any other way they want to D, not necessarily via C. Short-checking your luggage will be an issue. And if international travel is involved, there may be issues with required visas etc.

Comment: Note that even though the duplicate asks about not using the second leg rather than the first, the issue is the same (and worse actually if you don't take the first leg).

Comment: @qechua If there are any ‘tricks to take advantage of the cheaper price’ you can be pretty certain that a) the airline already has it covered in their T&C; b) the risks involved (late/cancelled flights, visa complications, luggage reclaim) mean it’s not worth it

Comment: @jcaron How is this a duplicate? This question is, essentially, "Do you have to take the _first_ leg of a flight?"

Comment: This is not a duplicate (at least it is not answered in the question that is linked at the top)

Comment: To answer the question: You will most likely be denied boarding if you only want to fly the B-C leg. Notice this is very different from taking only the A-B leg. There is very little the airline can do about you walking out at airport B (although the read the linked question to find out about all the caveats).

Comment: @DavidRicherby See my comment above. The reasons for the OP wanting to take only one of the legs are the same: hidden-city ticketing, which is discussed at length in the answers to that question. Here it's even worse as the traveller probably wouldn't even be able to use **any** flight at all, but the logic behind it is the same.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, also, as explained above as well, the answer to being able to take at least one flight is to switch from an A-B-C to a B-C-D ticket (where OP wants to take the B-C flight), and then we're back to the classic issue.